# No app icon after lunch

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using the newest sdk bundle with eclipse, and in a real simple app there is no Icon after launch and it's really bothering me why?

Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong?

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your icon named ic_launcher.png?  That is which one it IS using (there will be an icon in the various res folders with this name - that looks like this).  Google: Android Asset Studio.

Comment: yes, my icon is named ic_launcher.png, it is in 4 folders, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi. Folder drawable-ldpi is empty. Its just a standard hello world generated by eclipse. Any ideas why tehe is no icon ?